# Angular test how should import localize and translate pipes into the test bed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've just started to "learn" testing in angular, and my task is first just to successfully run ng test on a existing project.

Almost all of the default generated component tests has errors ("it should create"), since it has dependecies, like translate etc. I've just figured out that, I have to import some dependencies into the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` section, but for the translate and localize pipes which are coming from `@gilsdav/ngx-translate-router and @ngx-translate/core` is not working I got a `"The pipe 'localize' could not be found in the..."`. If I put  `imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()],` into the configureTestingModule it feels like it is working, but for the localize it is not (tried to put the localizeroutermodule in it)

My question is, how should I import these into the components test if I want to successfully load the ng test without errors firstly for the "should create" "it".

Angular 13.3, jasmine-core 3.10.0, karma 6.3.0"

Node 16.15.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like import like this:

```
imports: [RouterTestingModule, TranslateModule.forRoot(), LocalizeRouterModule.forRoot([])],
```

fixed it.